# How to insert only a portion of the JSON element into a SQL field

Tags: sql-server-2016, open-json

I'm using the following code in a SQL Server 2016 stored procedure and I would like to split the Journal ISSN value into 2 different fields.

```
DECLARE @json nVARCHAR(MAX) =
      '[{"Journal ISSN" : "15221059, 15309932"},
       {"Journal ISSN" : "23660058, 2366004X"}]'

INSERT INTO A_ADMIN_IMPACT_FACTORS_2020 ([Journal ISSN], [ISSN FirstEight],  [ISSN SecondEight_if Comma])
    SELECT [Journal ISSN]
    FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    WITH ([Journal ISSN] nvarchar(50))
```

I've tried to add

```
     SUBSTRING ([Journal ISSN],1,8) nvarchar(50)
```

in various spots but I'm sure the syntax is wrong.

Can someone point me in the right direction so that I end up with three columns?

- One with the complete value
- one with the first portion up the the comma or the entire value if no comma, and
- one with what remains after the comma

As I was typing this out it occurred that I might be able to use a computed column, but I would still like to know how I can do it in the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I got it;

```
     INSERT INTO A_ADMIN_IMPACT_FACTORS_2020 ([Journal ISSN], [ISSN Primary], [ISSN 
     Secondary])
     SELECT [Journal ISSN], SubString([Journal ISSN],1,8) as [ISSN Primary], CASE WHEN 
     CHARINDEX(',', [Journal ISSN]) > 1 THEN SubString([Journal ISSN], 11,8) ELSE '' 
     END AS [ISSN Secondary]
     FROM OPENJSON(@json)
     WITH ([Journal ISSN] nvarchar(50)
```